# Changing custom alert dialog's multi choice text color

Tags: java, android, xml, mobile

How does one change the text color of the multiple selectable items in a custom alert dialog:

```
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

That doesn't seem to be working in the styles xml, I want it to be red but its defaulting to black.

[image]

The title, positive, and negative buttons have been changed via:

```
    //negative button text color
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    //title text color
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

Comment: Paste your alertdialog code

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">#E91E63</item>
```